# Websocket error when using a proxy_pass to CRA development server using Nginx and Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I am trying to `proxy_pass` in Nginx to my React dev server at `localhost:3000`. It currently works but I am seeing an error in my console which I am unsure will cause any issues down the road:

> WebSocketClient.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/ws' failed:

**Nginx.conf**:

```
upstream backend {
    server backend:8000;
}

upstream frontend {
    server frontend:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
    
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding `WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0` to the frontend `.env` file also tried adding:

```
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
```

...as suggested in other SO posts. Neither worked.

What is this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding more in the variables

```
environment:
  - WDS_SOCKET_PORT=443
```

Maybe it can help you, but if you haven't proxy between, use WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0 in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
environment:
  - WDS_SOCKET_PORT=443
```

It works for me